# I can't retrieve data from server to android studio although data is shown in a browser

Tags: android, android-studio, android-volley

I have recently made an application in android studio 2.3 to show data from a server the link that I use is working properly in a browser and data is shown successfully in json format. But in my application I can't retrieve these data, I add avolley lib in my app gradle file like this :

> *compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.18'*

**The code I use in MainActivity is :**

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        RequestQueue rq;
        String url = "http://abdulwahid.esy.es/show.php";
        TextView txtshow;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            txtshow = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtshow);

            rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            JsonObjectRequest jor = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            try {
                                JSONArray jarr = response.getJSONArray("allstudents");
                                for (int i = 0; i < jarr.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject res = jarr.getJSONObject(i);
                                    String id = res.getString("id");
                                    String name = res.getString("name");
                                    String info = res.getString("info");
                                    txtshow.append("\n" + id + " - " + name + "\n" + info + "\n" + "------------------" + "\n");
                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    , new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("VOLLEY", "ERROR");
                }
            });
            rq.add(jor);
        }
```

The link of php file that I use is executed successfully in a web browser.
**How to show data in my application or is there another code or library to use for retrieving data form online ?**

Comment: Well what goes wrong?

Comment: `The link of php file that I use is executed successfully`. How do you know?

Comment: @greenapps, I try it in a web browser and it works successfully .

Comment: Well what goes wrong?????

Comment: @greenapps the wrong is when I use the code above in android studio and run it in a device or emulator nothing is show in the application.

Comment: did you ask for Internet access permission in the manifest?
https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html#manifest

Comment: Well then tell what happens instead. You should start telling us if onResponse() is called. If you dont tell then how we would know what hsppens?

Comment: @pantos27 I asked for the permission for the Internet access in manifest.

Comment: @Abdu what do the logs say?

Comment: @pantos27 using the code above gradle built successfully and nothing is shown in the textview.

Comment: @greenapps As u see in code above I used JSONObject to get the fields form the array "allstudents" then append data to the textview "txtshow".

Comment: My god of course i had seen that. But i askesd you to tell us if that code is executed. If onResponse() is invoked? If there is an exception you will also see nothing. Now tell what happens!

Comment: **1** you need to update the question, add what exception you are getting, (if there is any) **2** i tried to open the URL in browser, yes it works BUT it prints `Connected successfully` next to the JSON response, this makes your JSON invalid and cannot be parsed, so as a start remove that `Connected successfully` message, and try to application, if you have any exceptions, post them in the question **3** extract more details from VollyError instead of just logging the word "error"

Comment: @Yazan I have just delete the statement Connected successfully but the problem is still existed.

Comment: read the rest of my comment and do as much as you can. no one can fix a problem by just `guessing` we need to see some logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use StringRequest instead of jsonObject with the new library of volley

> compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'

Comment: Thanks for your response it is easier to use string request than jsonObject

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to retrieve data, in string line your data will be appended as a complete string as shown in browser

```
public void getData(){
        class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://abdulwahid.esy.es/show.php");

                // Depends on your web service
                httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

                InputStream inputStream = null;
                String result = null;
                try {
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                    inputStream = entity.getContent();
                    // json is UTF-8 by default
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    result = sb.toString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Oops
                }
                finally {
                    try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
                }
                return result;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result){
                myJSON=result;
                showList();
            }
        }
        GetDataJSON g = new GetDataJSON();
        g.execute();
    }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138537/discussion-on-answer-by-arun-mohan-i-cant-retrieve-data-from-server-to-android).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `Content-Type` header is not set in the response of your server. For Volley to be able to parse it, you will need that header set to `application/json`.

Add the following line in your `show.php`:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

**Edit**

After the above change, the response seems strange...

[image: Screenshot]

I can see strange characters in the response, that might be causing parsing issues on the client side.

Comment: I added this line in show.php but the data are not show in the application. this is a screenshot of php file https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_9G3EhgCUpDbjhLdmxOZEtDU2c/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I can see it set as text/plain on the top of the file too. Remove the top one and put this one on top.

Comment: Although this wont change anything, the last one is effective.